# Update column values to grouped comma-separated string if particular column is duplicate

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table like below:

ID  Name 
1   - a

1  - b

2  - c

3 -  d

I want to update the table like below

1  - a,b

2  - c

3  - d

Anybody Please help me on this